# android studio unable to start emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a problem to start the android studio emulator.
I am using Android Studio 2020.3.1 on windows 10.
I am using onboard graphic, don't have Graphic hardware.

**This the image is of error which I am facing to.**

[image]

Thanks anyone can give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Download the amdvlk64.dll file, extract the zip file and copy that .dll file, paste this file in C:\Windows\System32 then restart your emulator. dowload link - https://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=amdvlk64.dll&arch=64bit&version=1.0.54.0#

Comment: I tested it. Unfortunately did not helped!

Answer (score 0):

Open your AVD manager in Tool > AVD manager, it will show list of emulator devices your are using like this image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZerFt.png) , click the arrow dropdown at the end of your device, select wipe data option and open device again. make sure your device turn off before do above

Comment: my emulator does NOT have been run since I created !

Comment: hmm, open the avd manager and select edit option in dropdown menu of your device, at graphics, select automatic/hardware, then launch emulator again

Comment: my system has only onboard graphic. also I tried to change dropdown menu graphics in AVD manager .. but it's impossible :/